# 3 вопроса по C#

Tags: c#

1) Если привести в пример строчку кода:

```
string[] array = new[] { "ab", "abc" };
```

то `new[]` здесь будет означать то же, что и `new stirng[]`?

2) При создании экземпляра класса в стеке создаётся переменная, которая будет хранить адрес на область памяти в управляемой куче. Если этот класс наследуется от абстрактного класса, то что будет храниться в переменной в случае приведения к этому абстрактному классу?

3) В каком случае лучше всего использовать ключевое слово `var`?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это 3 не связанных вопроса в одном.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Да.

2) Зависит от реализации. Вам как программисту на C# это не должно быть интересно.

3) Когда компилятор позволяет, а вам лень писать имя типа.

Answer (score 1):

По поводу 1) и 2) мне нечего добавить к принятому ответу.

По поводу 3), вы должны пользоваться явным типом там, где вы хотите акцентировать внимание на точном типе. А там, где вас больше интересует значение, а конкретный тип не так уж и важен, используйте `var`.

По моему опыту, `var` нужен в процентах 90 случаев, но YMMV.